# Why does typing rand(100,60) into Microsoft Word result in it creating 81 pages?

Tags: windows-7, ms-word

I have a very simple Office utility question.

Open Microsoft word (2003 or 2007), whatever you use.

- Let's have a new empty blank document (it's up to you to have it or not)
- Press enter to go to a new line
- now type "=rand(100,60)" in new line
- Now press enter
- After writing this - it will create 81 pages long story

The question is what exactly is Microsoft Word doing?

Comment: Microsoft Word is not exactly the kind of product that would resort to publicity like this.  You don't need the clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This is a known feature.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/212251)

100 is the number of paragraphs; 60 is the number of sentences per paragraph.